# Interaction term gender interpretation stata

Tags: regression, interaction, regression-coefficients, stata, categorical-encoding

[image]

Hi,

I have a hard time interpreting these coefficients in collum 2. 
So my dependent variable is if you have a supervisory job yes=1 and my independent variables are female=1 and traditional values=1. Now how can i compare the likelihood of a supervisory job for traditional men vs traditional woman, should i then add trad*fem+ female?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Was this estimated using least squares?

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes this is a OLS regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're partial to linear probability models, I would also suggest fitting a maximum likelihood logit model.

> Now how can I compare the likelihood of a supervisory job for traditional men vs traditional woman, should I then add trad*fem + female?

You're on the right track. First, to get a precise estimate, you should also report your *intercept*.

\begin{align*}
\widehat{\text{Supervisor}} &= \hat{\alpha} + 0.086\text{Traditional} - 0.214\text{Female} - 0.169(\underbrace{\text{Traditional}\times\text{Female}}_{\text{Interaction}}) \\
\end{align*}

The interaction shows how the effect of traditional values on obtaining a supervisory position is modified by gender. All you have to do is keep track of which dummies are turned 'on/off' as you interpret your model.

First, the probability of a *non-traditional male* securing a supervisory position is the *base condition* (i.e., the intercept). The probability of a *male* with *traditional values* obtaining a supervisory position is the base condition plus 0.086 (i.e., $\text{Traditional} = 1$). The interpretation of the coefficient on $\text{Traditional}$ is the effect of exhibiting traditional values on the probability of obtaining a supervisory position *with all other predictors equal to 0*. To put this in the context of your equation, the estimate for the effect of *traditional men* in your sample is as follows:

\begin{align*}
\widehat{\text{Supervisor}} &= \hat{\alpha} + 0.086(1) - 0.214(0) - 0.169(1 \times 0) \\
\widehat{\text{Supervisor}} &= \hat{\alpha} + 0.086
\end{align*}

This is your estimate of the probability of a *traditional male* landing a supervisory job. Now, you correctly note that a *female* with *traditional values* is the effect when $\text{Traditional = 1}$ *and* $\text{Female = 1}$, so you should assess the combined effect of these two coefficients.

The main effect of being a *non-traditional female* is *negative* (i.e., -0.214). You can think of this as offsetting the male intercept. In non-technical terms, females start with a lower probability. The interaction of the *traditionalist* variable with *gender*, though, further offsets the effect of being female. Here is the final derivation:

\begin{align*}
\widehat{\text{Supervisor}} &= \hat{\alpha} + 0.086(1) - 0.214(1) - 0.169(1 \times 1) \\
\widehat{\text{Supervisor}} &= \hat{\alpha} + 0.086 - 0.214 - 0.169 \\
\widehat{\text{Supervisor}} &= \hat{\alpha} - 0.297
\end{align*}

In sum, these estimates allow you to compare traditionalist men with traditionalist women. Your model suggests non-traditional women have a lower probability of securing a management position, *and* their chances are further reduced if they espouse traditional values.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: @Sabine If this helped, please select this as the answer using the check mark on the left.